# Drupal 8 Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception

Tags: drupal-8

Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.

Original

```
Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'drupal8new.users' doesn't exist: SELECT u.*, s.* FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.sid = :sid; Array ( [:sid] => jTk-DdIj4XlzQsnH86R22ktqje2PUFx7RcfnngiQJJg ) in Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->query() (line 569 of /var/www/drupal8new/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Connection.php).

Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->query('SELECT u.*, s.* FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.sid = :sid', Array)
Drupal\Core\Session\SessionHandler->read('IIBgOUpsx2qnDOPFcwY_1VKaZrjxC48SVzaOOoKEi78')
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\WriteCheckSessionHandler->read('IIBgOUpsx2qnDOPFcwY_1VKaZrjxC48SVzaOOoKEi78')
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy\SessionHandlerProxy->read('IIBgOUpsx2qnDOPFcwY_1VKaZrjxC48SVzaOOoKEi78')
session_start()
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start()
Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManager->start()
Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManager->initialize()
Drupal\Core\Authentication\Provider\Cookie->authenticate(Object)
Drupal\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationManager->authenticate(Object)
Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy->getAccount()
Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy->id()
Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannel->log(6, '%module module installed.', Array)
watchdog('system', '%module module installed.', Array, 6)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->install(Array, )
drupal_install_system(Array)
install_base_system(Array)
install_run_task(Array, Array)
install_run_tasks(Array)
install_drupal()
Additional
```

RuntimeException: Failed to start the session: already started by PHP. in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start() (line 134 of /var/www/drupal8new/core/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php).

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start()
Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManager->start()
Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManager->initialize()
Drupal\Core\Authentication\Provider\Cookie->authenticate(Object)
Drupal\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationManager->authenticate(Object)
Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy->getAccount()
Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy->id()
Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannel->log(3, '%type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).', Array)
watchdog('php', '%type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).', Array, 3)
_drupal_log_error(Array, 1)
_drupal_exception_handler(Object)
```

How to fix this erro

Comment: I got the same error.